# What Does x-bit integer mean?

Tags: binary, type-conversion, integer

I have a very basic question related to the data type.

if I have one array of let say **5** elements

```
x = [3.23 1.47 3.79 8.91 6.01],
```

and it's data type is **8-bit** integer.

Does it mean that each entry in the above array can be represented by **8** binary bits and it can take the values from **-128 to 127** OR from **0 .. 255** ? OR something else.

Comment: There's a decimal point `.` in the data (e.g. `3.23`, `1.47` etc.), that's why I suspect the actual data type is *floating point* `single`, `double` etc., but not *integer*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer is another word for "whole number." For example: 1 and -17 are integers, while 3.23 and pi are not. Your array is not an array of integers.

There are 256 different possible values for 8 bits. There are two common choices for which 256 numbers to use: unsigned and signed. The unsigned 8 bit integers are 0, 1, 2, ..., 255, and the signed are -128, -127, ..., +127.